# How can I correct this syntax error in this sql query with array_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to include `order by` in line 35 and 43 in the query below. I want to order the option and field models by `order` column, ascending. But I am getting a syntax error:

```
syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 42:      )) AS "fields"
```

I am using postgresql. The full code is below:

```
WITH qs AS (
    SELECT
        "issQuestion".*,
        array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
            'id',  "responses"."id",
            'questionId', "responses"."questionId",
            'title', "responses"."title",
            'createdAt', "responses"."createdAt",
            'updatedAt', "responses"."updatedAt"
        )) AS "responses"
    FROM question AS "question"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "question_response" AS "responses" ON "question"."id" = "responses"."questionId" AND "responses"."supervisionId" = 59
    WHERE "question".id = 135
    GROUP BY "question".id, "question".title, "question"."createdAt", "question"."updatedAt"
), qs_op AS (
    SELECT
        qs.*,
        array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
            'id',  "options"."id",
            'text', "options"."text",
            'score', "options"."score",
            'order', "options"."order"
        )) AS "options"
        order by 'order' ASC,
        array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
            'id',  "fields"."id",
            'name', "fields"."name",
            'label', "fields"."label",
            'order', "fields"."order",
            'isNumeric', "fields"."isNumeric"
        )) AS "fields"
        order by 'order' ASC,
    FROM qs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "question_option" AS "options" ON qs.id = "options"."questionId"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "question_field" AS "fields" ON qs.id = "fields"."questionId"
    GROUP BY qs.id, qs.title, qs."createdAt", qs."updatedAt", qs."responses"
), qs_op_2 AS (
    SELECT
        qs_op.*,
        array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
            'id',  "ft"."id",
            'name', "ft"."name"
        )) AS "associatedFacilityTypes"
    FROM qs_op
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "question_facility_type" AS "iqf" INNER JOIN "fac_type" AS "ft" ON "ft"."id" = "iqf"."facilityTypeId") ON qs_op.id = "iqf"."questionId"
    GROUP BY qs_op.id, qs_op.title, qs_op."createdAt", qs_op."updatedAt", qs_op."responses", qs_op."options", qs_op."fields"
)
SELECT * FROM qs_op_2
ORDER BY qs_op_2.id;
```

Comment: put the `order by` after the `group by`. Also, you might wanna order by `"order"` instead of `'order'` cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `ORDER BY` corresponds to the data used inside `ARRAY_AGG()` function. In which case it must be placed inside the function (complete syntax is [described here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)):

```
array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
  'id',  "options"."id",
  'text', "options"."text",
  'score', "options"."score",
  'order', "options"."order"
) ORDER BY "options"."order" ASC) AS "options"
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct as it is used inside the ARRAY_AGG function. But because order is a reserved word I had to do ```ORDER BY "options"."order" ASC``` and  ```ORDER BY "fields"."order" ASC```